# React: get user phone number

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-api, google-oauth

I am developing React js app where the user can log in using google account , I want to retrieve the registered phone number for the user by using firebase login.

I have followed this tutorial to make the login flow
https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react

> my question is : Can I get the phone number of the user when he/she
>   logged into my system using google email ?

this is part of the code I use to login

```
firebase_ui_instance.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
                signInFlow:'popup',
                signInOptions: [ {
                        provider: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                        // Required to enable this provider in one-tap sign-up.
                        authMethod: 'https://accounts.google.com',
                        scopes: [
                            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
                            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
                            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read'
                        ],
                        customParameters: {
                            // Forces account selection even when one account
                            // is available.
                            prompt: 'select_account'
                        },
                        // Required to enable ID token credentials for this provider.
                        // This can be obtained from the Credentials page of the Google APIs
                        // console.

                        clientId: '[MY_CLIENT_ID]',
                        credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.GOOGLE_YOL

                    }
```

I was able to get many info about the user(email,full name...) but not the mobile number...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the API on this page and tried to execute the query on the right hand side?
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get

You'll get the access token and you'll need to use to make the API call.